# align the dropped divs in a container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**Description**

I have a container div that has little divs with pictures on them..
what works perfect is when I click any one of them(div) it comes out and do stuff that is assigned to it.
Now I can drag any div I want back into the container but the problem is the div when dropped in the container stays at the place where it is left. I want to align all the divs in the container at the top when ever droped.

e.g when I drag any div back into the container it should be aligned with all other divs in the container.

**What have I tried ?**

I have tried to give the dropped div

`position: inherit` with jquery . but that only works if there is 1 div to drag and drop.

**Have I searched StackOverflow form answers ??**

Yes I have and I found a solution

[found solution demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7f5DF/6/)

but it involves the clonning of the divs which in my case is not required.
Can any one help me ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it solve your problem if you add a "remove" line in your solution? E.g. :

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop:function(e,ui){
        if($(ui.draggable).parent().attr("id")!=$(this).attr("id")){
           var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone();
            clone.removeAttr("style");
            clone.appendTo($(this));
            $(ui.draggable).remove(); // Remove original element
        }
    },
    revert:true
});
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/xu2dm7gj/1/